# How to split two columns in a table in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

There is table of data

```
1 2

1 3

33 34

10 22

11 23

25 26

27 28

.....
```

now I need to split data in the two columns and merge them in to a single list The code I have written below does the job for single digit numbers but not for two or three digit numbers.

```
myfile = open("karate.txt","r") #read and write to a file 

for line in myfile.read():   # read data in the file
    fields = ' '.join(line.split()) # split columns of table based on space   
    print fields
    rows = map(int,fields) # converting tuple to integer
    data.extend(rows)
```

The output of this code for the above data is

```
1


2


1


3


3

3


3

4


1
```

but I need the output as

```
1

2

1

3

33

34

11

23

25

26

27

28
```

Comment: Have you tried to load the file with `np.loadtxt`. Then the data is loaded as a matrix which I think is more easy to handle.

Comment: I know that numpy would be more easier but my professor has not allowed us to use numpy constructs so it has to be more naive approach... but thanks for the reply...

Comment: And yet you tag your question with the numpy tag...

Answer (score 2):

The problem can essentially be divided into two stages: Read in the numbers as a list containing lists, then [flatten the list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/646543).

```
fields = []
with open("text.txt") as f:
    fields = [line.split(' ') for line in f]

print fields
# [(1, 2), (1, 3), (33, 34), (10, 22), ...etc... ]

flattened = [i for tup in fields for i in tup]
print flattened
# [1, 2, 1, 3, 33, 34, 10, 22, 11, 23, ...etc...]

# Print line by line:
print '\n'.join(flattened)
```

This should print out the output that you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Method 1
fields = []
with open("testfile.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        fields.extend(line.split())  # Note that the elements are "strings".

print("-" * 50)
print(fields)
print("-" * 50)
print("On separate lines")
print('\n'.join(fields))
print("-" * 50)
print("With lines in between")
print("\n\n".join(fields))
print("-" * 50)

# Method 2
fields = []
with open("testfile.txt") as infile:
    map(lambda line: fields.extend(line.split()), infile)

print("A slightly shorter implementation")
print(fields)
print("-" * 50)
```

**Output:**

```
--------------------------------------------------
['1', '2', '1', '3', '33', '34', '10', '22', '11', '23', '25', '26', '27', '28']
--------------------------------------------------
On separate lines
1
2
1
3
33
34
10
22
11
23
25
26
27
28
--------------------------------------------------
With lines in between
1

2

1

3

33

34

10

22

11

23

25

26

27

28
--------------------------------------------------
A slightly shorter implementation
['1', '2', '1', '3', '33', '34', '10', '22', '11', '23', '25', '26', '27', '28']
--------------------------------------------------
```